# Convert list from API do dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data as a list which looks like as following.

```
name                   type              value
Api_collect            list [5]          List of length 5
 country               character [1]        US
 state                 character [1]        Texas
 computer              character [1]        Mac
 house                 character [1]        Mansion
 president             character [1]        Trump
```

The following code have I runned in R.

```
api_col <- base::rawToChar((response$country))

as.data.frame(api_json$country)
```

And results in this df:

```
country
US
```

How to transfer this list to a dataframe with every column of `Api_collect` except for `house`?

Comment: Try `do.call(data.frame, mylist)`

Comment: ```as.data.frame(api_json$country)``` + ```as.data.frame(api_json$state)``` + ```as.data.frame(api_json$computer)``` + ```as.data.frame(api_json$president)``` . I can make these into four unique tibbles. Is there a way to use the ```map_df``` function because the only difference in the code is $variable. ? @JustJames

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using `purrr::map_df()` and `dplyr::select()`:

```
# name                   type              value
# Api_collect            list [5]          List of length 5
#  country               character [1]        US
#  state                 character [1]        Texas
#  computer              character [1]        Mac
#  house                 character [1]        Mansion
#  president             character [1]        Trump

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

your_list <- list(
    country = "US",
    state = "Texas",
    computer = "Mac",
    house = "Mansion",
    president = "Biden"
)

purrr::map_df(your_list, ~.x) %>% select(-country)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  state computer house   president
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    
1 Texas Mac      Mansion Biden
```